# I get this error when I try to add an array to my angular syncfusion grid

Tags: angular

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
> at Column.AppComponent.valueAccess [as valueAccessor]

These are the codes of the `app.component.html`

```
<e-column field="Validity" headerText="Validity Period" [valueAccessor]="valueAccess">
```

These are the codes of the `app.component.ts` file

```
public valueAccess = (field: string, value: object, column: object) => {
  this.val = this.dateformatter(new Date(value[field][0])) + ' - ' + this.dateformatter(new Date(value[field][1]));
  return this.val
}
```

Comment: Apparently, value[field] is undefined, but you try to get index 0 of it. What does value look like?

Comment: The `valueAccess`, as you wrote it, returns a string.